How can CCextractor CLI be setup as batch file to a network share?
I have a shared "Movies" folder on my Qnap NAS.
I need a batch file to accomplish two things on the MPG files inside of it.
First with CCExtractor.exe to genearate each file's .srt. The current path of CCExtractor is on D:\CCExtractor. I am stumped primarily here. I do not know what the commands would be to take each MPG file, run CCExtractor.exe against it and then proceed to the next MPG file. Afterwards hand off to the step below.
Second, I need CRC64.exe to process those files next. I know the syntax for it would be: "D:\BRC\BRC64.exe" /dir:"L:\Movies" /RegExp:"(.+?)( \d{7,8})? [\d{6,8}-\d{4,6}]$:\1"

@echo off

cd /d "L:\Movies" || exit 

set "_cmd=C:\Program Files (x86)\CCextractor\ccextractorwinfull.exe" 


for /f usebackq^ ^delims^= %%i in =;(` where .:*.mpg `);= do "%_cmd%" "%%~i" -o "%%~dpni.srt"

"D:\Full\Path\To\BRC64.exe" /dir:"L:\Movies" /RegExp:"(.+?)( \d{7,8})? [\d{6,8}-\d{4,6}]$:\1"

timeout -1



Worked! Thank you for your help!
